# Python. Output of crypto.cipher.blowfish and .AES can be translated neither into unicode (as sqlite wants), nor into hex

Tags: python, sqlite, encryption

Okay, I'm totally new to Python, so I decided to make a simple app. Here is my encryption function:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
def encPass(login, password):
    keyPhr=os.environ['HOME']+login
    hashObj = hashlib.md5()
    hashObj.update(keyPhr)
    keyPhr=hashObj.hexdigest()
    keyObj=AES.new(keyPhr)
    encPwd=keyObj.encrypt(password+'pssd')
    return encPwd
```

as you see, it gets login and pass, and encrypt pass with binding to pc.

The problem is when i try to feed encPws to sqlite3 and insert it into a table, it says:

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

If i try to put encPwd in unicode() or hex():

```
TypeError: hex() argument can't be converted to hex
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 0: unexpected code byte
```

I guess it's because i'm newbie, but what should I do? The same with Blowfish instead of AES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `buffer` and insert the `encPwd` as a blob.

Or you can use something like [base64](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html#module-base64) to convert your `encPwd` to ASCII (which is a subset of UTF8) so you can insert it as a string.

Comment: base64 says "incorrect padding". this is kind of dark sorcery?

Comment: Only b64decode would give "incorrect padding". You use b64encode to turn encPwd into a string suitable for the database, and use b64decode to convert back into the original encPwd value.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's what autocomplete is all about, thanks a lot!